# View details of connection error in Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, debug

When Firefox cannot connect to some server, I want to view the ***actual error*** instead of some "user-friendly" message such as this, which is not helpful at all:

> Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.
>
> We can’t connect to the server at [www.wawawiwa.com](http://www.wawawiwa.com).
>
> If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:
>
> - Try again later.
> - Check your network connection.
> - If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.

In this case a more sensible message would be `DNS error: Cannot resolve name www.wawawiwa.com`.

Is there a way to achieve this in Firefox, or in some Firefox fork/modification (Pale Moon, etc.)?

I am specifically looking for a way to debug various *network connection* errors, e.g. DNS error, no route available, TCP handshake timeout, RST received from peer, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tools in firefox to gather developer level information on connection errors.

- Go to `about:networking`.
- Go to Logging section.
- Now set a log file location.
- Now click Start logging.
- Reproduce the connection error issue.
- Now click on Stop logging.
- Go to the folder and search for .MOZ_LOG files (Usually log-main).
- Open them with a text editor and use find dialog box to get information about `wawawiwa.com` or any other errors.

Hope that helps

Comment: Why is the first error necessary?

Comment: Oh @Arctilic accidentaly typed that its not neccessary, edited the post

Comment: Thanks for the tip. By default the information is so immensely detailed and there are so many log entries that it's practically impossible to figure out what the actual problem is. But this I'll play with the various log modules and levels and see what I can squeeze out of it.